# Add names to list items, so that the names are individually paired to the items in the code

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a simple question about naming list items.

My data is in a list, simplified example below. I can add names to list items using `names()`:

```
models <- list("fit_1", "fit_2", "fit_3")

names(models) <- c("simple", "extended", "log linear")
```

which gives a named list in this form:

```
models
#> $simple
#> [1] "fit_1"
#> 
#> $extended
#> [1] "fit_2"
#> 
#> $`log linear`
#> [1] "fit_3"
```

Is there any way I can enter list items and names as pairs? With my real data, with a longer list and more complicated items, it would be nice to be able to easily check that say item 27 in the list is correctly matched with the 27th name.

My desired outcome would be to be able to do something like this:

```
models <- list(
  "fit_1" = names("simple"),
  "fit_2" = names("extended"),
  "fit_3" = names("log linear")
)
```

and then to get a named list.

I'd be particularly interested if there's an easy tidyverse way.

Comment: why not simply list(fit1 = "simple", fit2="extended",fit3="log linear") ?

Comment: I think this is pretty much the answer I'm looking for. I can't mark it best answer, because it's a comment.

Comment: I put it as answer, so that the question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 list(fit1 = "simple", fit2="extended",fit3="log linear")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is asking for a pipe, use function

```
`names<-`
```

as in

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

models <- list("fit_1", "fit_2", "fit_3")
newnames <-c("simple", "extended", "log linear")

models %<>% `names<-`(newnames)
models
#$simple
#[1] "fit_1"
#
#$extended
#[1] "fit_2"
#
#$`log linear`
#[1] "fit_3"
```